# How to add two (2) Button on Fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

I was following the tutorial here: *https://gist.github.com/EmmanuelGuther/1fde5cfbd1cdcd21cd852e3bb5716e02*.

I have one button which computes the total from user input. It uses the layout **fragment_ab.xml**. I would like to add a **"Clear"** button but I do not know how to add a second button.

In the main activity I would just use **clear.setOnClickListener{}** alongside **compute.setOnClickListener{}** but it doesn't work here. I'm new to fragments.

Here's the code:

```
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

    class AbActivity: Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View {
            val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ab, container, false)
            val btn: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.compute)
            btn.setOnClickListener(this)
            return view
        }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): AbActivity{
            return AbActivity()
        }
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.compute -> {
                Toast.makeText(
                    activity,"Yay!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else -> {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `fragment_ab.xml` code.

Comment: You can add another button same as you have added first button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button in you `fragment_ab.xml` with id = `clear` and then do as following:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class AbActivity: Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ab, container, false)
        val btn: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.compute)
        btn.setOnClickListener(this)

        // for clear button
        val btnClear: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.clear)
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(this)
        return view
    }

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): AbActivity{
        return AbActivity()
    }
}

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (v?.id) {
        R.id.compute -> {
            Toast.makeText(
                activity,"Yay!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        // clear button click
        R.id.clear -> {
            Toast.makeText(
                activity,"Clear!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else -> {
        }
    }
}
```